# use MVC model with jsp

Tags: java, jsp, google-cloud-datastore

I know what in theory MVC mean but i never developed with this model.In my servlet I get a list from the Datastore

```
 int pageSize = 20;
        FetchOptions fetchOptions = FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(pageSize);

        Query q = new Query("post").addSort("time", SortDirection.DESCENDING);
        PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q);

        QueryResultList<Entity> results = pq.asQueryResultList(fetchOptions);
        System.out.println("-------------------");
        for (Entity entity : results) {

 System.out.println(entity.getProperty ("content"));
 System.out.println(entity.getProperty ("time"));
        }
```

And now I want to show this result ( contents and times ) in the jsp page. I don't know honw to do it because I think I can't use a PrintWriter because the jsp page is already there with all the css, forms and I think if i will put this code ( getting the data from the database ) in the jsp page, it will be an infraction and it will not be a MVC model ?

Answer (score 2):

Right, putting the code to JSP will violate the MVC pattern, because you are putting controller code in the view.

If this is the servlet code, than you should do:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("page.jsp").forward(request, response);
                              ^ path to your page
```

Also, you should add your data to the session

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("content", results);
```

In the jsp page, you just read this data.

Comment: Use page/request/session/application contexts depending on what you need.

Comment: Once on the page, you can use JSTL's foreach loop and expression language to access the properties you wish to display

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer says if you put that code in your JSP it will violate MVC pattern you may want to reconsider your project setup and link your entity file to your JSP with a system like Struts, that seems to be a pretty common way of going about things and there is plenty of documentation on it on this site and in other places around the web, a good place to start might be http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/docs/home.html

I know specfically for what you seem to be trying to do using the Struts system it would be something like

```
<s:property value="variable" />
```

Then that would keep your model, and view seperate.